# OpenCV's Face detection sample doesn't work on android

Tags: eclipse

I tried to execute the openCV sample of face Detection, but it didn't work. This is what's displayed in the console:

```
*14:08:47 **** Auto Build of configuration Default for project OpenCV Sample - face-detection1 ****
/bin/bash /home/NVPACK/android-ndk-r8e/ndk-build NDK_DEBUG=1 V=1 
/home/NVPACK/android-ndk-r8e/build/core/add-application.mk:128: Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-9 is larger than android:minSdkVersion 8 in ./AndroidManifest.xml    
rm -f ./libs/armeabi/lib*.so ./libs/armeabi-v7a/lib*.so ./libs/mips/lib*.so ./libs/x86/lib*.so
rm -f ./libs/armeabi/gdbserver ./libs/armeabi-v7a/gdbserver ./libs/mips/gdbserver ./libs/x86/gdbserver
rm -f ./libs/armeabi/gdb.setup ./libs/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup ./libs/mips/gdb.setup ./libs/x86/gdb.setup
Gdbserver      : [arm-linux-androideabi-4.6] libs/armeabi-v7a/gdbserver
install -p /home/NVPACK/android-ndk-r8e/prebuilt/android-arm/gdbserver/gdbserver ./libs/armeabi-v7a/gdbserver
Gdbsetup       : libs/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup
echo "set solib-search-path ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a" > ./libs/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup
echo "directory /home/NVPACK/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include "../../sdk/native/jni/include/opencv" "../../sdk/native/jni/include" /home/NVPACK/android-ndk-r8e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/include /home/NVPACK/android-ndk-r8e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi-v7a/include" >> ./libs/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup
Install        : libdetection_based_tracker.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libdetection_based_tracker.so
install -p ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libdetection_based_tracker.so ./libs/armeabi-v7a/libdetection_based_tracker.so
/home/NVPACK/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-strip --strip-unneeded  ./libs/armeabi-v7a/libdetection_based_tracker.so

14:08:47 Build Finished (took 478ms)*
```

I used the TADP (Tegra Android Development Pack) version for Android, openCV 2.4.5, and Eclipse 3.8.